# How to wait for a queue to contain elements?

Tags: java, queue, wait

I'm trying to implement a FIFO observer/observable decoupling queue, but I am not sure how to get a method to wait until a queue is not empty before returning. Here's is my current attempt but I'm sure there must a more elegant solution.

```
/*
 * Waits until there is data, then returns it.
 */
private Double[] get() {
    while (queue.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Don't care.
        }
    }

    return queue.removeFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) - this does exactly what you want.

Comment: Please link at least to the Java 6 version of that document, for it has a nice table there.

Answer (score 4):

The [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface has a [`take()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take--) method for this purpose.